# How to get all leading characters before the first instance of a number

Tags: ruby

I have product codes that look like:

```
abc123
abcd23423
```

I need to get all the leading characters before the first instance of a number, so:

```
abc
abcd
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: are the product codes supposed to be on the same line or separate lines?

Comment: @Greg: Based on the source code of the question, separate lines. I've highlighted the plain text appropriately. @Blankman: look at the preview next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 "abc123 abcd23423".scan(/(\D*)\d+/)
  => [["abc"], [" abcd"]]

 "abc123 abcd23423".scan(/(\D*)\d+/).join
  => "abc abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'abc123 abcd23423'.split(/\d+/).join
```

or just

```
'abc123 abcd23423'.gsub(/\d+/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA.each do |l|
  chars = l[/^([[:alpha:]]+)/, 1] # [:alpha:] = [a-zA-Z]
  puts chars
end

__END__
abc123
abcd23423

# >> abc
# >> abcd
```

If you want to capture the alpha into an array do something like this:

```
ary = []
DATA.each do |l|
  ary << l[/^([[:alpha:]]+)/, 1] # [:alpha:] = [a-zA-Z]
end
ary # => ["abc", "abcd"]

__END__
abc123
abcd23423
```

I didn't use `\D` because it means all non-numeric (AKA `[^0-9]`), but that can be dangerous if you are going to run into any other text that is not an alpha character:

```
'abc_-$%#123'[/^(\D+)/, 1] # => "abc_-$%#"
```

For the same reason `\w` is not necessarily safe:

```
'abc_-$%#123'[/^(\w+)/, 1] # => "abc_"
```

`[[:alpha:]]` is the alphabet characters `[a-zA-Z]`

```
'abc_-$%#123'[/^([a-zA-Z]+)/, 1] # => "abc"
'abc_-$%#123'[/^([[:alpha:]]+)/, 1] # => "abc"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has a bug where code at the start of a question can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression which detects the beginning of the string (`\A`) and tries to capture as many non-digit characters (`\D*`) as possible (`*` is greedy by default):

```
processed_codes = codes.map { |code| code.scan(/\A(\D*)/)[0] }
```

You can also use `String#match` of course, but it has less predictable/intuitive behavior.